# Synchronous Wait Without Blocking the UI-Thread

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, multithreading, wait

Is there a synchronous wait function that won't tie up the UI-thread in .NET WPF?  Something like:

```
Sub OnClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles button1.Click
     Wait(2000) 
     'Ui still processes other events here
     MessageBox.Show("Is has been 2 seconds since you clicked the button!")
End Sub
```

Comment: in plain Win32 you can use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects to achieve this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for that sort of thing.

**Edit:** This might do as well...

```cs
private void Wait(double seconds)
{
    var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    new Thread((ThreadStart)(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
            frame.Continue = false;
        })).Start();
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}
```

([`Dispatcher.PushFrame` documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.pushframe.aspx))

---

Starting with .NET 4.5 you can use [`async`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) event handlers and [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the same behaviour. To simply let the UI update during such a handler return [`Dispatcher.Yield`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh965189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: In WPF you defiantly want to use the DispatcherTimer as it's ticks will execute on the UI's thread enabling you to modify UI controls. If you use a standard timer the ticks execute on its own thread and you will get some nasty exceptions if you try to touch UI controls. +1

Comment: Is there anyway to use the timer to do the waits inline.  Seems cumbersome and hard to read when you break up a method every time you need a wait.

Comment: @PeterM: As i'm not all too well versed in threading issues you might want to take a look at the [Threading Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) reference and the [`Dispatcher.PushFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.pushframe.aspx) method, which might help you simplify this.

Comment: @PeterM: Actually i think i just got a solution using this method, see my updated answer. (I don't speak VB though...)

Comment: As an example [A non blocking wait for event in C#](https://medium.com/home-wireless/a-non-blocking-wait-for-event-in-c-6662ba47373)

Comment: This solution works but should used with care. See [Which blocking operations cause an STA thread to pump COM messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21573637/8051589) for example. Quoted from that answer: <That said, I'd never recommend using something like WaitOneAndPump for production code (besides for very few specific cases). It's a source of various problems like UI re-entrancy.>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `Task.Delay`. I'm using it in unit-tests for `ViewModel`s that use `DispatcherTimer`.

```
var frame = new DispatcherFrame();

var t = Task.Run(
    async () => {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
        frame.Continue = false;
    });

Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);

t.Wait();
```