# For each loop doesn't sleep

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a For..Each loop which loops trough all grid's rectangles and changes the fill of them randomly. I change the fill with a color animation. Here's my code:

```
        Dim rand as new random
        Dim changeColor As New Animation.ColorAnimation

        changeColor.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)

        For Each r As Rectangle In Grid.Children
            changeColor.From = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(r.Fill.ToString)            
            Dim i As Integer = rand.Next(0, 2)
            Select Case i
                Case 0
                    changeColor.To = Colors.White
                Case 1
                    changeColor.To = Colors.Gray
            End Select
            Animation.Storyboard.SetTarget(changeColor, r)
            Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(changeColor, New PropertyPath("Fill.Color"))
            Dim sb As New Animation.Storyboard
            sb.Children.Add(changeColor)

            sb.Begin()
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0.5)
        Next
```

The problem is that the loop doesn't sleep. I want to trigger the animation, then wait until the rectangle fill is changed and then continue with the rest, but it seems that all of the rectangles fill are changed in the same time. So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're putting the main thread to sleep. This means the animation will probably not even start until after the thread.sleep finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sleep the UI thread, so both the loop and all rendering is halted. You could try a method like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117293/synchronous-wait-without-blocking-the-ui-thread/6117313#6117313) i wrote for another question.

**Edit:** Also change the time as pointed out by Michael Holdshteyn.

Comment: Could you please convert the code from your answer to VB.NET?

Comment: @Cobold: I do not speak VB.NET, but [this converter tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) might help you. (Also i would say that C# really is not hard to understand in comparison with VB.NET)

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0.5)
```

With:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
```

The sleep value is an integer and [is in Milliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). When you do `Sleep(0.5)` all you're getting is a context switch.

Comment: This doesn't work, it just waits 0.5 seconds for each rectangle I have and only after it has processed all rectangles it changes their color.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep takes in  MILLISECONDS as the time.  So you're saying that you want this to sleep for 0.5 milliseconds (or 0.00005 seconds).

Which may or may not be enough to finish the task.

Then, there's also the possibility that you're running in the same thread as the UI. If that's the case, then unless you invalidate the visual, the screen won't refresh until you finish processing.