# Sleep inside for loop in wpf

Tags: wpf, multithreading, sleep

I have been working with WPF and threading.

I would like to pause the whole screen (the application only) during a for loop.

E.g.

```
foreach (classA a in classesA)
{
....
....
Thread.sleep(100);

}
```

However, I found that it will sleep for long and then execute all the statement in a time.
It is not what I want. I want to sleep within the execution of the for loop. That is to sleep 100ms after 1st loop, then sleep again after the 2nd loop.....

I found that some article mentioned DoEvents(), but I am not quite familiar with it and WPF seem don't have this kind of thing.

Some other articles mentioned DispatcherTimer. Still, it will not lock the screen.
I would like to lock the whole screen (the application only) to prevent from clicking any button during the execution of the for loop.

How could I do so?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to experiment to with the proposed `async` and `await` keywords you could achieve the sleep behavior with synchronous semantics like this. You would need to install the [Async CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9983) to do it though.<sup>1</sup>

```
public aysnc void YourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  foreach (classA a in classes)
  {
    await Task.Delay(100);
  }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>*The Async CTP uses `TaskEx` instead of `Task`.*

Answer (score 4):

You must not block the UI-thread otherwise it cannot process its queue, which contains rendering the UI, if you want to block interaction with UI-elements set `IsEnabled=false` on a root element, then to do a non-blocking wait see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117293/).

Comment: I have tried to make the Page IsEnabled=false. However, it turns some of my control from black to white, so ugly!! how to solve it?

Comment: @user883434: You'd have to modify the template, if they were black to begin with someone did not properly style the state when they are disabled...

Comment: An alternative is to set `IsHitTestVisible` to False if you don't like the look of disabled controls. This makes elements ignore clicks.