# WPF delay a function that fills a table

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I have a `Table` control, and I want to fill it with colors, with a delay of `X` milliseconds between each paint.

This a very general example of what I am doing (It's longer, but I deleted the unimportant lines):

```
private void myFunc()
{
     while (SOME_CONDITION) {
          Thread.Sleep(X_MS);
          this.myTable.RowGroups[0].Rows[SOME_ROW].Cells[SOME_COLUMN].Background = Brushes.Blue;
     }
}
```

The above just freezes the `Window` until the function is done, and paints the desired cells in a single moment.

I know I shouldn't use `Sleep`, but when I worked on a console application, it was an easy solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: your are blocking the current UI thread by doing a sleep. answer articulated/can be derived from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078596/sleep-inside-for-loop-in-wpf

Comment: You may use a DispatcherTimer as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16978840/1136211).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use new async features

```
private async void myFunc()
{
    while (SOME_CONDITION) {
        await Task.Delay(X_MS);
        this.myTable.RowGroups[0].Rows[SOME_ROW].Cells[SOME_COLUMN].Background = Brushes.Blue;
    }
}
```

because of WPF`s synchronization context table editig will be performed on UI thread